# php pagination result Limit per page

Tags: php, search

Using Simple Dom Parser , I have above 50 result, Now i want result only 10 Per page. My search.php page have this following code

```
<?php 
 include('simple_html_dom.php');
 $search = $_GET['search']; 
 $html = file_get_html('http://mysite/'.$search.'.html');

foreach ( $html->find('div#song_html ') as $e ) {

$title= $e->find('div', 2)->plaintext;

 echo $title.'<br>'; 
}
?>
```

Now i calling my page using this code show all above 50 result ..

```
 http://domain/search.php?search=Keyword
```

I want per page 10 result Like &startrow=1 means first 10 result &startrow=2 means second 10 result

```
 http://domain/search.php?search=Keyword&startrow=1 //page 1 with 10 result
 http://domain/search.php?search=Keyword&startrow=2 //page 2 with Next 10 result
 http://domain/search.php?search=Keyword&startrow=3 //page 3 with Next 10 result
```

Comment: Sorry but you ask for a PHP Dom parser. This is wrong, it's correct to paginate your results. Simply put an integer variable, than you multiplicate your limit for that var. That var will be your "page" number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could work with `array_slice()` on the result of the DOM parser... Something like the following code could do the trick (untested code):

```
<?php 

include('simple_html_dom.php');
$page = array_key_exists('startrow', $_GET) ? (int)$_GET['startrow'] : 1;
$search = $_GET['search']; 
$html = file_get_html('http://mysite/'.$search.'.html');

$songs = $html->find('div#song_html ');
$paginationStart = min((10 * ((int)$page - 1)), (count($songs)-1));

$results = array_slice($songs, $paginationStart, 10);
foreach ( $results as $e ) {
    $title= $e->find('div', 2)->plaintext;
    echo $title.'<br>'; 
}

?>
```

Comment: Edited answer to have a fallback when someone enters a ridiculously high `startrow`